# SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, camunda, system.net.webexception, camunda-modeler

I am windows developer trying to use Camunda model rest API client project.
I did download the sample from the GIT which has examples for Camunda samples using WPF.

https://github.com/mtringuyen/camunda-dot-net-showcase

However there seems to be some sort of socket exception.
IIS is installed. I also verified versioning of .NET STANDARD and .NET FRAMEWORK. They are compatible.

[image]

Any suggestions to resolve this error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is obviously no application listening on that specific (8080) port ...

Answer (score 1):

The project you are using only contains

- a .NET tasklist implementation used by people to participate in the business processes.
- .NET implementation of automated task workers, which are used to do system integration from .NET (See: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/external-tasks/)

The Camunda server remains a Java application. However, you can start it and use it as a blackbox from .NET without Java knowledge. There are several distributions. If you are not familiar with Java you should either use the Docker image:

```
docker run -d --name camunda -p 8080:8080 camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest
```

or a prepackages Tomcat using the Camunda RUN distribution.
You can download a server here: https://camunda.com/download/

Also see: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/installation/

Answer (score 0):

If you think an application that is running is listening on a particular port a quick way to check would be to run a command prompt as administrator and do a netstat -ab .  This will show you all the ports that are listening on your local device.  Obviously your example requires something listening on 8080 so fire up whatever application that is supposed to be and double check it.